# golang: trying to use `any` to match different functions

Tags: go, any

Given this function:

```
func Apply(label string, func(msg any, arg any) (any, error) {
...
}
```

Unfortunately the `func`s I need to pass to `Apply` don't match in their signature.

```
//Func 1
func GetAddress(prompt string, custom Param) (string, error) {}

// Func 2
func GetIdentifier(prompt string) (utils.ID, error) {}
```

But why does the compiler (go1.18) complain if I try

```
Apply(label, GetAddress)
```

with

> [compiler IncompatibleAssign] [E] cannot use GetAddress   (value of
> type func(prompt string, custom Param) (string, error)) as
> func(msg any, arg any) (any, error) value in argument to Apply

Why does `msg any` not match to `prompt string`, `custom Param` not to `arg any` and the `string` type in the return not to the `any` type in the return?

What exactly is incompatible here? (Ignore if you think the design is bad for a sec, I just want to understand that first).

Comment: https://go.dev/doc/faq#covariant_types

Comment: It's tempting to think because`any` can be assigned any *value* it will match any *type*. `string` and `any` are different types and thus the function signatures don't match.

Comment: Are you trying to use go generics? No "any" type in go

Comment: @DenizAktürk ["any is an alias for interface{} and is equivalent to interface{} in all ways."](https://pkg.go.dev/builtin#any)

Answer (score 2):

Change the func declaration to use type parameters

```golang
func Apply[T1 any, T2 any, T3 any](label string, func(msg T1, arg T2) (T3, error)
```

Now to call it

```golang
Apply[string, Param, string](label, GetAddress)
```

When the function has type parameters, you may be able to drop the type parameter list with the compiler automatically inferring what the variant types are:

```golang
Apply(label, GetAddress)
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason why the code you wrote doesn't actually work is that the types have to match exactly in the go language. The interface type is valid for incoming value types, the definition types must be the same in function, however, if the definition type is interface (or "any"), the parameter value can be any. (string|int ...)

```
func Apply(label string, func(msg any, arg any) (any, error) {
...
}

//Func 1
func GetAddress(prompt any, custom any) (any, error) {}
// Func 2
func GetIdentifier(prompt any) (any, error) {}
```

Answer (score -1):

func Apply[K any](label string, func(msg K, arg K) (K, error) {
...
}

maybe something like this could work

**Apply[K any]**